# Capture Giftcard in Video

Tags: html, image, video, image-processing

Have you seen Apple's App Store functionality that allows you to [capture a giftcard number with your webcam](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5556)?

Would it be possible to do this with a web interface? If so, how? Here's my initial thoughts:

1. Use the [HTML5 getUserMedia API](http://davidwalsh.name/browser-camera) to capture the video
2. Every second or so capture a screenshot
3. With either front end scripting (JS) or backend scripting (PHP in my case) search the image for the number
4. Send the number to the server for validation

1, 2, & 4 don't seem that hard. The hardest part is processing the image for a number. Are there any JS or PHP libraries out there to do this? Or am I overthinking the entire thing and there's an easier way of doing this?

A screenshot of Apple's Giftcard redemption via webcam:
[image: Giftcard]

Comment: for #3 check out this library https://github.com/manuels/unix-toolbox.js-exact-image/, or for a WebRTC integrated example (of a different library) this https://github.com/brauliobo/webrtc-samples/tree/master/barcode-scanner

Comment: Thanks for the barcode scanner. In this case our coupon system doesn't create a barcode so that wouldn't be of much help but it would certainly work for others.

Comment: doesn't look like there's much in the way of full OCR out there, though this https://github.com/antimatter15/ocrad.js got a couple of references... you might have to do some more Google-diving to find what you're after (or add barcodes!)